# c++ project link static and shared libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, libstdc++

I have a c++ project. Its project structure is presented below:

```
.
|--src
|   |--foo
|   |   |--foo.h
|   |   |--foo.cpp
|   |   |--CMakeLists.txt
|   |
|   |--bar
|       |--bar.h
|       |--bar.cpp
|       |--CMakeLists.txt
|
|--main.cpp
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

I add `foo` and `bar` as static libraries by using `add_library(foo STATIC ${FOO_DIR})` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

`main.cpp` links to `foo` and `bar` libs using static linking.

Now I have some 3rd party shared libs, for example, `abc.so`.

In top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(my_proj)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static")

#find abc libs
find_package(abc REQUIRED)
...

#adding foo bar subdirectories
...

add_executable(my_proj main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_proj foo bar abc)
```

When main.cpp links `foo`, `bar` and `abc.so`, it shows the error:
`attempted static link of dynamic object /xxx/abc.so`

What should I do to link shared and static libs simultaneously?

**update**

If I try to remove `-static`, it shows the error:

```
ibQt5Core.a(qstringlist.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt3pmr25monotonic_buffer_resourceD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.28'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

It links to libstdc++ shared library, even though I explicitly used

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc")
```

What should I do to link static libstdc++?

Comment: Did you try removing `-static` from the manually-altered flags in your CMake file?

Comment: Hi, if I remove `-static`, it shows the error: `ibQt5Core.a(qstringlist.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt3pmr25monotonic_buffer_resourceD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.28'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`

Comment: "It links to libstdc++ shared library, even though I explicitly used" - Yes, `abc.so` links to `libstdc++` as shared library. It is how that library **has been built**. Obviously, this build is unaffected by setting of `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` in your project, when you just *use* the library. If you need your project to use static standard libraries, then 3d party libraries you use should also be built in that way.

Comment: I still have questions: Why my `*.a` lib cannot find the reference to libstdc++? It should be able to link libstdc++.